# не работает else

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть у меня такой код

```
            } else {?>  
            <div class="detail_picture">
                <meta content="<?=($isDetailImg ? $arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC'] : SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/images/no-photo.jpg');?>" itemprop="image" />
                <?if($isDetailImg) {?>
                    <a rel="lightbox" class="catalog-detail-images fancybox" href="<?=$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']?>"> 
                        <img src="<?=$arResult['DETAIL_IMG']['SRC']?>" width="<?=$arResult['DETAIL_IMG']['WIDTH']?>" height="<?=$arResult['DETAIL_IMG']['HEIGHT']?>" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />
                <?} else {?>
                    <div class="catalog-detail-images">
                <?if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['PHOTO1']){?>     <img src="/upload/img/<?echo $arResult['PROPERTIES']['PHOTO1']['VALUE'] ;?>" width="150" height="150" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />      <?} else {?>        <img class="item_img" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/no-photo.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />   <?}?>
                <?}?>

                <div class="sticker">
                    <?=$sticker?>
                </div>
                <?$arVendor = $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MANUFACTURER"]["FULL_VALUE"];
                if(is_array($arVendor["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])) {?>
                    <img class="manufacturer" src="<?=$arVendor['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']?>" width="<?=$arVendor['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['WIDTH']?>" height="<?=$arVendor['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['HEIGHT']?>" alt="<?=$arVendor['NAME']?>" title="<?=$arVendor['NAME']?>" />
                <?}
                unset($arVendor);?>
                <?=($isDetailImg ? "</a>" : "</div>");?>                            
            </div>                  
    </div>
        <?}?>
```

Вот этот кусок кода не хочет работать, а точнее else

```
            <?if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['PHOTO1']){?>     <img src="/upload/img/<?echo $arResult['PROPERTIES']['PHOTO1']['VALUE'] ;?>" width="150" height="150" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />      <?} else {?>        <img class="item_img" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/no-photo.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />   <?}?>
```

где я тут ошибся?   свойство PHOTO1 пустое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если рассматривать только второй кусок приведенного Вами кода, то в коде:

```
<?if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['PHOTO1']){?>     <img src="/upload/img/<?echo $arResult['PROPERTIES']['PHOTO1']['VALUE'] ;?>" width="150" height="150" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />      <?} else {?>        <img class="item_img" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/no-photo.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="<?=$strAlt?>" title="<?=$strTitle?>" />   <?}?>
            <?}?>
```

У вас тут в конце лишняя `}`

upd:

а если рассматривать первый приведенный вами код, то у Вас там `</div>` вылез не туда или его не хватает в нужном месте (трудно сказать, т.к. нет всего кода)
но скорее всего у Вас просто лишний закрывающий `div`

Comment: Это закрывающая else

Comment: обновил ответ рассмотрев первый код

Comment: В общем у Вас там один лишний закрывающий `<div>`

Comment: не думаю что дело в div, там есть код который закрывает, но на всякий проверил, только верстка слетела

Comment: Вот на скриншоте показал: https://yadi.sk/i/6_5kf1V7W-xbTQ - div точно один лишний, он мог сюда закрасться из-за ошибок ранее в коде или забрел сюда, а должен быть после показанного кода. Именно в php коде я ошибок не нашел., разве только переменные у Вас не заполняются до их использования или имеют не те значения, что Вы используете в приведенном коде

Comment: разобрался откуда этот див, вытащил его за } а значение оно пустое, если не пустое то все работает прекрасно

Comment: Спасибо @Firsov36 что помог))

Comment: нет, я говорю что все так же) этот div ничего не решил))

Comment: Ну `div` тоже являлся ошибкой из-за которой вы потом "тааакую верстку" могли бы отловить, что как минимум + я заработал))

Comment: А по существу вопроса: `if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['PHOTO1']) {` поменяйте на `if (isset($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['PHOTO1']) && strlen($arResult["PROPERTIES"]['PHOTO1']["VALUE"])>0) {`